# Maps autocomplete: limit by cities, villages included

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

When I limit the autocomplete to cities, the villages are gone also.

Any idea how to fix that?

```
var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
     componentRestrictions: {country: "be"}
    };
```

E.g.: Lesdain, brunehaut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var options = {
      types: ['(regions)'],
     componentRestrictions: {country: "be"}
    };
```

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types

It's not possible to limit just by cities and villages